# Permissions denied on apache rewrite module virtual host configuration

Tags: httpd, rhel6

All of a sudden I keep getting "Permissions denied" on apache 2 virtualhost once we moved it to its own conf file. I have tried all the suggestions I have found here but none work. Please can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot "/var/www/mm"
<Directory "/var/www/mm">
Options +Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order deny,allow
Allow from all

AddType text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor        .jad
AddType application/vnd.rim.cod .cod
</Directory>

Alias /holdspace "/var/www/mm/holdspace"

RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteLog "/var/log/httpd/rewrite.log"
RewriteEngine on

# 91xx

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} BlackBerry.9105
RewriteRule ^/download/(.*) /holdspace/bb6-360x480/$1 [L]

# 92xx

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} BlackBerry.9220
RewriteRule ^/download/(.*) /holdspace/bb5-320x240/$1 [L]
```

Errors in error.log:

```
[Wed May 28 12:44:58 2014] [error] [client 197.255.173.95] (13)Permission denied: access     to /download/eazymoney.jad denied
[Wed May 28 12:44:58 2014] [error] [client 197.255.173.95] (13)Permission denied: access     to /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var denied
[Wed May 28 12:44:59 2014] [error] [client 197.255.173.95] (13)Permission denied: access     to /favicon.ico denied
[Wed May 28 12:44:59 2014] [error] [client 197.255.173.95] (13)Permission denied: access     to /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var denied
[Wed May 28 12:44:59 2014] [error] [client 197.255.173.95] (13)Permission denied: access     to /favicon.ico denied
[Wed May 28 12:44:59 2014] [error] [client 197.255.173.95] (13)Permission denied: access     to /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var denied
```

Errors in rewrite.log:

```
197.255.173.95 - - [28/May/2014:12:46:01 +0100] [41.203.113.103/sid#7fe41704ca28][rid#7fe417123378/initial/redir#1] (3) applying pattern '^/download/(.*)' to uri '/error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var'
197.255.173.95 - - [28/May/2014:12:46:01 +0100] [41.203.113.103/sid#7fe41704ca28][rid#7fe417123378/initial/redir#1] (3) applying pattern '^/download/(.*)' to uri '/error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var'
```

Apache Configuration file:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerRoot "/etc/httpd"
PidFile run/httpd.pid
Timeout 60
KeepAlive Off
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
<IfModule worker.c> 
StartServers         4
MaxClients         300
MinSpareThreads     25
MaxSpareThreads     75 
ThreadsPerChild     25
MaxRequestsPerChild  0
</IfModule>
Listen 80
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_alias_module modules/mod_authn_alias.so
LoadModule authn_anon_module modules/mod_authn_anon.so
LoadModule authn_dbm_module modules/mod_authn_dbm.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_owner_module modules/mod_authz_owner.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_dbm_module modules/mod_authz_dbm.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule ldap_module modules/mod_ldap.so
LoadModule authnz_ldap_module modules/mod_authnz_ldap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule logio_module modules/mod_logio.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule ext_filter_module modules/mod_ext_filter.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule expires_module modules/mod_expires.so
LoadModule deflate_module modules/mod_deflate.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule usertrack_module modules/mod_usertrack.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule dav_module modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module modules/mod_dav_fs.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule speling_module modules/mod_speling.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule substitute_module modules/mod_substitute.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
LoadModule suexec_module modules/mod_suexec.so
LoadModule disk_cache_module modules/mod_disk_cache.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
Include conf.d/*.conf
User apache
Group apache
ServerAdmin root@localhost
ServerName sv001zma002.africa.int.myorg.com
UseCanonicalName Off
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
<Directory /> 
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Options  FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    UserDir disabled
</IfModule>
DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var
AccessFileName .htaccess
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</Files>
TypesConfig /etc/mime.types
DefaultType text/plain
<IfModule mod_mime_magic.c>
    MIMEMagicFile conf/magic
</IfModule>
HostnameLookups Off
ErrorLog logs/error_log
LogLevel warn
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent
CustomLog logs/access_log combined
ServerSignature Off
TraceEnable Off
Alias /icons/ "/var/www/icons/"
<Directory "/var/www/icons">
    Options  MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule mod_dav_fs.c>
    DAVLockDB /var/lib/dav/lockdb
</IfModule>
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/cgi-bin/"
<Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
IndexOptions FancyIndexing VersionSort NameWidth=* HTMLTable Charset=UTF-8
AddIconByEncoding (CMP,/icons/compressed.gif) x-compress x-gzip
AddIconByType (TXT,/icons/text.gif) text/*
AddIconByType (IMG,/icons/image2.gif) image/*
AddIconByType (SND,/icons/sound2.gif) audio/*
AddIconByType (VID,/icons/movie.gif) video/*
AddIcon /icons/binary.gif .bin .exe
AddIcon /icons/binhex.gif .hqx
AddIcon /icons/tar.gif .tar
AddIcon /icons/world2.gif .wrl .wrl.gz .vrml .vrm .iv
AddIcon /icons/compressed.gif .Z .z .tgz .gz .zip
AddIcon /icons/a.gif .ps .ai .eps
AddIcon /icons/layout.gif .html .shtml .htm .pdf
AddIcon /icons/text.gif .txt
AddIcon /icons/c.gif .c
AddIcon /icons/p.gif .pl .py
AddIcon /icons/f.gif .for
AddIcon /icons/dvi.gif .dvi
AddIcon /icons/uuencoded.gif .uu
AddIcon /icons/script.gif .conf .sh .shar .csh .ksh .tcl
AddIcon /icons/tex.gif .tex
AddIcon /icons/bomb.gif core
AddIcon /icons/back.gif ..
AddIcon /icons/hand.right.gif README
AddIcon /icons/folder.gif ^^DIRECTORY^^
AddIcon /icons/blank.gif ^^BLANKICON^^
DefaultIcon /icons/unknown.gif
ReadmeName README.html
HeaderName HEADER.html
IndexIgnore .??* *~ *# HEADER* README* RCS CVS *,v *,t
AddLanguage ca .ca
AddLanguage cs .cz .cs
AddLanguage da .dk
AddLanguage de .de
AddLanguage el .el
AddLanguage en .en
AddLanguage eo .eo
AddLanguage es .es
AddLanguage et .et
AddLanguage fr .fr
AddLanguage he .he
AddLanguage hr .hr
AddLanguage it .it
AddLanguage ja .ja
AddLanguage ko .ko
AddLanguage ltz .ltz
AddLanguage nl .nl
AddLanguage nn .nn
AddLanguage no .no
AddLanguage pl .po
AddLanguage pt .pt
AddLanguage pt-BR .pt-br
AddLanguage ru .ru
AddLanguage sv .sv
AddLanguage zh-CN .zh-cn
AddLanguage zh-TW .zh-tw
LanguagePriority en ca cs da de el eo es et fr he hr it ja ko ltz nl nn no pl pt pt-BR   ru sv zh-CN zh-TW
ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
AddType application/x-x509-ca-cert .crt
AddType application/x-pkcs7-crl    .crl
AddHandler type-map var
AddType text/html .shtml
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
ProxyErrorOverride On
Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
<IfModule mod_include.c>
    <Directory "/var/www/error">
        AllowOverride None
        Options IncludesNoExec
        AddOutputFilter Includes html
        AddHandler type-map var
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        LanguagePriority en es de fr
        ForceLanguagePriority Prefer Fallback
    </Directory>
    ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
    ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var 
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
BrowserMatch "Mozilla/2" nokeepalive
BrowserMatch "MSIE 4\.0b2;" nokeepalive downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "RealPlayer 4\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Java/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "JDK/1\.0" force-response-1.0
BrowserMatch "Microsoft Data Access Internet Publishing Provider" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "MS FrontPage" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDrive" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^WebDAVFS/1.[0123]" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^gnome-vfs/1.0" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^XML Spy" redirect-carefully
BrowserMatch "^Dreamweaver-WebDAV-SCM1" redirect-carefully
ErrorDocument 400 "Bad Request"
```

Comment: Please add the line from the error log where the error occurs.

Comment: I don't see any ServerName directive in your virtualhost config. Are you sure that the right config is being applied?

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but does it absolutely need to have one? And if so can I just use an IP address? Or the server's real host name?

Comment: If you don't have a ServerName, apache won't know which servername the config applies to. And your error log looks as though this config isn't being applied, since the paths in the error logs don't contain the directory you've got in your virtualhost config.

Comment: I gave it a host name (the server's full hostname) and nothing's changed. Error messages are still the same.

Comment: I think it'd be nice to see the rest of the apache config too at this point.

Comment: I just dropped into the original question. That was a LOT of indenting!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is with this part in your main config:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error/HTTP_BAD_REQUEST.html.var
ErrorDocument 401 /error/HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED.html.var
ErrorDocument 403 /error/HTTP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
ErrorDocument 404 /error/HTTP_NOT_FOUND.html.var
```

Those directives are affecting the entire server, including the VirtualHost. But the previous part, which is:

```
Alias /error/ "/var/www/error/"
```

won't affect the virtualhost - because the Alias works for the main server, not for the VirtualHost.

So, in order to make the error documents work, you will need to make sure that the configuration for error handling is available in the same context as the virtual host configuration. As it is, you're referencing a path that doesn't exist within the VirtualHost context.

(It's not clear to me whether you are using your webserver for more than one site. If everything is reached using the same hostname, then there is really no reason to split some config off to a VirtualHost.)

Comment: Thanks! But yes the server is being used by quite a few sites. Im not really sure i know what to do / how to fix. Please could you explain a bit more?

Comment: I've commented out the ErrorDocument lines, removed the ServerName from the virtualhost context, restarted apache and I still have the same error messages (less the Error Document message, this is cleared). I am wondering where to post this output. Do I have to edit the main question again?